# how to reassign the app directory to another directory name in Next.js?

Tags: bash, next.js, npm-scripts

I want to be able to host several app pages so I can have multiple apps in the same repo.

File structure:

```
/
  /components.js
    /SharedComponent.js
  /app
    page.js
  /app2
    page.js
  /app3
    page.js
```

So from the build I could pick if I want to build `app` or `app2`.

This would allow me to have multiple apps sharing the same common components and reduce the maintainability of dependencies. Also would reduce issues with maintaining a monorepo/workspace setup.

I tried with Sym links but seems to not be working because Next.js thinks that `app2` is the link even if the `app` directory is present but links to `app2`.

I also tried with deleting the content from `app` and replacing it with `app2`. That works but the problem is that I have to restart the app every time I do changes to the pages.